# get rss feeds for weather forecast

Tags: android

I am trying to get weather forecast details for 3 days for user location. I cant find any content providers providing weather forecast details with weather code. So, anyone please suggest me which api can i use to get this information. I will ready also to pay for the feeds. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google weather feed (its not advertised) but you're allowed to use it.

http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=london

You'd need to search for params for it - but as far as i remember you can pass in cities, countries etc.